# Move vertical scrollbar up anytime datagrid is refreshed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

Hello Everybody I am new in C#.  I have a some data that in load in my datagrid but anytime the datagrid has new items loaded my vertical scroll bar stays in the same position!

How to move up my scroll bar anytime the datagrid has new values or I click to a new button

move vertical scrollabar up anytime the datagrid is refresh
[image: move vertical scrollabar up anytime the datagrid is refresh]

Comment: Welcome to SO. First lesson: C# is not C.

Comment: Okay so any idea about my question? please @Gerhardh

Comment: No, but if you add wrong language tag, the wrong people will look into your question who might not know much about C# (like me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGrid class has a method `ScrollIntoView` which can be used to scroll a specific item into the visible area of the datagrid.

For example, to scroll to the first item of the datagrid:

```
datagrid.ScrollIntoView(datagrid.Items[0]);
```